# Перезапуск видеозахвата

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencv

В одном из проектов под Linux, использующем OpenCV, потребовалось осуществить перезапуск захвата кадров с видеокамеры. Всё как обычно, за исключением того, что в какой-то момент требуется прекратить считывать кадры, закрыть файл устройства, а затем активировать видеозахват по новой.

Тем не менее, данная, в общем-то тривиальная операция завершается с ошибкой. Ниже - минимальный компилируемый код, воспроизводящий проблему:

```
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

bool capture() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    if(!cap.open(0)) return false;

    while(1) {
        cv::Mat mat;
        cap >> mat;

        if(mat.empty()) return false;

        break;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    if(!capture()) return -1;
    if(!capture()) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке, после вывода которой программа завершает свою работу:

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by
>   OpenCV VIDIOC_STREAMON: Bad file descriptor Unable to stop the
>   stream.: Bad file descriptor

Выводятся эти сообщения исключительно при повторном запуске функции `capture()` из примера. Пытался по всякому останавливать работу `cv::VideoCapture`, но профит достигнут не был. Результат один и тот же.

Нашёл в Сети упоминание о том, что загрузка библиотеки совместимости с Video4Linux первой версии, предваряющая запуск программы видеозахвата, может помочь решить проблему. Проще говоря, нужно сначала выполнить команду:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

И это действительно помогло. Ошибка, обозначенная выше, исчезла, однако стало выводиться предупреждение при каждом перезапуске видеозахвата:

> libv4l2: warning v4l2 mmap buffers still mapped on close()

На это можно было бы и не обращать внимания, в конце концов перезапуск видеозахвата стал работать без каких-либо ошибок, но выяснилось, что в этом случае не происходит высвобождение памяти, выделенной под видеобуфер. В итоге каждый раз теряется от 20 мегабайт ОЗУ, что совершенно неприемлемо, поскольку перезапуск видеозахвата требуется осуществлять довольно часто на протяжении всей жизни процесса.

Как победить?

З.Ы. Пока же остановился на том, что переписал код видеозахвата на использование ffmpeg. Последний не повторяет обозначенное поведение - видеоустройство корректно открывается и закрывается.

З.З.Ы. Ошибка воспроизводится на версиях Ubuntu от 14.04 до 15.04 (x86 и amd64) включительно, на разных видеокамерах и OpenCV 3 rc1. На более ранних версиях OpenCV не пробовал, но высока вероятность, что тоже самое, т.к. код видеозахвата, как мне кажется, не претерпел больших изменений со второй версии фреймворка.

**Update:**
оказывается, это давняя [проблема](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2822).

Comment: Вообще это все очень странно...
Создается впечатление, что у вас программа собиралась с объектником cap_v4l, а не cap_libv4l. В последнем это уже было исправлено.

Comment: Ваше замечание верно, libv4l я не ставил. Эта библиотека сама по себе является обёрткой, поэтому особого смысла в ней не видел, раз уж OpenCV умеет работать с video4linux2 напрямую.

Comment: В смысле оберткой? В cap_libv4l все реализовано тоже через video4linux2 напрямую. Эти два файла имеют почти идентичную функциональность и цель.

Comment: правильно, но я имею в виду выбор: `v4l2 -> libv4l -> opencv` или `v4l2 -> opencv`. Очевидно, что libv4l в цепочке лишняя, если не даёт чего-то большего, нежели чем модуль cap_v4l. А это именно так, поскольку класс `VideoCapture` предоставляет одинаковые возможности при использовании любого из двух модулей. А если нет разницы, зачем платить больше? Впрочем, риторический вопрос, т.к. затраты на лишнюю прослойку безусловно минимальны.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли... я виду речь тоже об opencv.
Есть два файла opencv/modules/videoio/src:
cap_libv4l.cpp 
cap_v4l.cpp.
Они почти идентичны и оба работают напрямую с v4l2.

Comment: Не совсем. В файле cap_libv4l.cpp в самом начале проверяется макрос `HAVE_LIBV4L`, который ставится в истину при конфигурировании OpenCV и в том случае, если в системе установлен пакет libv4l. Соответственно, используется именно libv4l, хотя и переопределены некоторые её конструкции.

Comment: Т.е. речь идет о том, что
(ioctl(capture->deviceHandle, VIDIOCSYNC, &capture->mmaps[capture->bufferIndex].frame)
это вызов ядра
а
(v4l1_ioctl(capture->deviceHandle, VIDIOCSYNC, &capture->mmaps[capture->bufferIndex].frame)
это через библиотеку?

Comment: Да, так точно. Вы можете посмотреть исходники libv4l и обнаружите там `v4l1_ioctl()` и `v4l2_ioctl()`. При этом заголовочные API ядра `linux/videodev.h` и `linux/videodev2.h` таковых функций не объявляют.

Comment: Это тогда бардак... файлы очень схожи и при добавлении какой-либо функциональности/исправления бага, например, являющиеся темой данного обсуждения, необходимо править в двух местах...
надо что-то с этим делать...

Comment: OpenSource - если что-то не устраивает, всегда можно поправить. Если правка объективная, то её примут разрабы, ведущие проект.

Comment: А вы как считаете non-libv4l vs libv4l? У какого подхода какое преимущество?
Чем вы руководствовались компилируя код без поддержки libv4l?

Comment: libv4l получается просто как дополнительная обёртка. Она бы имела смысл, если бы конечный класс `VideoCapture` в связи с её использованием дополнялся какой-либо ещё функциональностью. Но этого нет, поэтому и нет особого смысла в использовании libv4l. Конечно при условии, что вариант с non-libv4l будет функционировать, как положено, что в общем-то, после исправления обнаруженного бага вроде соблюдается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на основании информации в [первом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/428178/178576) попробовал представить логику вызова кода внутри функции `icvCloseCAM_V4L()` в виде матрицы (для написания правильного патча).

сейчас так:

```
                              | +HAVE_CAMV4L | -HAVE_CAMV4L
                              +----------------------------
+HAVE_CAMV4L2 V4L2_SUPPORT==1 |    close2    |      -
+HAVE_CAMV4L2 V4L2_SUPPORT==0 |    close1    |    close2
-HAVE_CAMV4L2                 |    close1    |      -
```

а должно быть, по идее, так (разница во втором столбце):

```
                              | +HAVE_CAMV4L | -HAVE_CAMV4L
                              +----------------------------
+HAVE_CAMV4L2 V4L2_SUPPORT==1 |    close2    |    close2
+HAVE_CAMV4L2 V4L2_SUPPORT==0 |    close1    |      -
-HAVE_CAMV4L2                 |    close1    |      -
```

legend:

- +name — name is defined
- -name — name is undefined
- close1 — close v4l device
- close2 — close v4l2 device

@alexis031182, как вы считаете, я уловил суть верно?

**upd**
интуиция мне подсказывает, что достаточно инвертировать условие проверки `V4L2_SUPPORT` (вместо `==0` поставить `==1`) и поменять местами блоки кода, реализущие `close1` и `close2` вместе с обрамляющими каждый из блоков `ifdef`.

т.е., используя «упрощённую» схему, примерно так:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     if (V4L2_SUPPORT == 1)
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     {
       /* Code for close V4L2 device */
     }
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#if defined(HAVE_CAMV4L) && defined(HAVE_CAMV4L2)
     else
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L && HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L
     {
       /* Code for close V4L device */
     }
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L */
```

вроде бы, получается то, что надо.

**upd2** отправил [pull request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/4099) и добавил комментарий к [сообщению об ошибке](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2822).

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Если есть возможность реализовать патч и он будет принят, то это будет здорово.

Comment: интуиция мне подсказывает, что достаточно инвертировать условие проверки `V4L2_SUPPORT`  (вместо `==0` поставить `==1`) и поменять местами блоки кода, реализущие `close1` и `close2` (вместе с обрамляющими каждый из блоков `ifdef`).

Comment: @alexis031182 , если у вас есть возможность, проверьте, пожалуйста, работоспособность [патча](https://gist.github.com/sash-kan/c368d6115f9977cacc7f). у меня возможности нет ввиду отсутствия камеры.

Comment: Александр, спасибо. Применил патч и пересобрал релизную версию 3.0. Подтверждаю, код из патча функционирует как надо: устройство закрывается правильно и новое открытие не блокируется.

Comment: @alexis031182 , спасибо! отправляю pull request на github-е. upd: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/4099

Comment: добавил комментарий к [багу](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2822)

Comment: Спасибо. Там баг, правда, к С'шной версии относится (также видел для Питона аналогичный с теми же симптомами), но с другой стороны текущая реализация на плюсах, она как просто обёртка над старым функционалом. Не стали видимо заморачиваться особо, когда переписывали. Впрочем, может это и не нужно - переписывать под C++ с нуля этот функционал, не знаю.

Comment: ну, главное, чтобы патч *корректно* исправлял ошибку, а то, что ошибка за это время перекочевала из одной реализации в другую, по-моему, не очень существенно.

Comment: патч [приняли](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/4099#event-333087739).

Comment: отлично! Респект :)

Answer (score 1):

Поработал с исходниками OpenCV. Оказалось, что разрабы просто перемудрили с макросами `HAVE_CAMV4L` и `HAVE_CAMV4L2` в файле **cap_v4l.cpp**, находящемся в **opencv/modules/videoio/src**.

Суть ошибки: не закрывался видеопоток, не освобождалась память (munmap), не закрывался файл устройства в функции `icvCloseCAM_V4L()` (строка 2819).

Причина: нарушается логика закрытия V4L2-устройства в случае, если макрос `HAVE_CAMV4L2` определён (defined), а `HAVE_CAMV4L` - нет. При этом, если определены оба, то всё будет работать правильно.

В исходнике:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     if (V4L2_SUPPORT == 0)
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L
     {
       /* Code for close V4L device */
     }
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L */
#if defined(HAVE_CAMV4L) && defined(HAVE_CAMV4L2)
     else
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L && HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     {
       /* Code for close V4L2 device */
     }
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
```

Переменная `V4L2_SUPPORT` типа `int` имеет значение `1` в случае, если на момент выполнения программы и подключения устройства используется V4L2 и значение `0`, если используется V4L. Соответственно, если макрос `HAVE_CAMV4L` не определён, а `HAVE_CAMV4L2` определён, то итоговый код при компилляции получится следующий:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     if (V4L2_SUPPORT == 0)
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
#ifdef HAVE_CAMV4L2
     {
       /* Code for close V4L2 device */
     }
#endif /* HAVE_CAMV4L2 */
```

... а поскольку при использовании V4L2-устройства переменная `V4L2_SUPPORT` становится равна `1`, то и код закрытия устройства никогда не выполнится.

Данную ошибку можно исправить различно, но в самом простейшем случае или, например, при нежелании заморачиваться достаточно присвоить переменной `V4L2_SUPPORT` значение `0` аккурат перед указанным кодом с макросами.

Comment: Вышедший сегодня релиз 3.0 к сожалению не содержит исправление проблемы.